# How do I initialise a class within a class

Tags: c#, class, initialization

In C# I have a class like this:

```
public class BClass
{
    public int Ndx { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This is then used within this class

```
public class AClass
{
    public int Ndx { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public BClass[] Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I populate author I do not know how many titles they have until run time so the number of instances of `AClass.Titles` there will be, so my question is how do I initialise this every time, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use a __List<BClass>__? I mean, if you don't know the size of the array then you should just use a __List<T>__ where you can add your _T_ items after the initialization without worring about any size (with reason of course)

Comment: Consider creating an AClass (do please use better names even in academic examples for posting on SO) property in BClass, so the link is bidirectional. Given any book you can get the author and for any author you can get the books

Comment: Also, just a note on naming.. Probably most devs would hear you say "class within a class" and assume you were talking about an inner class, eg `public class Outer{ ... public class Inner { ... } }` where the Inner is declared inside the scope of Outer. Here the more correct way to phrase the question would be "how do I initialize an array *property* of a class when I don't know how many items I will have?" - the fact that it's a BClass array is immaterial; it could as easily have been a string[] and the advice to use List would remain valid. Also check out what other collections c# has..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an array you can use a collection type like **List<BClass>**. This way, you can dynamically add BClass instances at runtime without worrying about the initial size of the array. This is how to do it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ClassName
{
    public int titleNum { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public List<BClass> Titles { get; set; }

    public ClassName()
    {
        Titles = new List<BClass>();
    }
}
```

Here is how to add items to the collection:

```
ClassName a = new ClassName();
a.titleNum = 1;
a.author = "Author Name";

a.Titles.Add(new BClass { titleNum = 1, Title = "Title 1" });
a.Titles.Add(new BClass { titleNum = 2, Title = "Title 2" });
```